# Removing all occurrences of a key only removes one

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
        ArrayList<GregorianCalendar> toRemove = new ArrayList<GregorianCalendar>();
SortedSet<GregorianCalendar> copyKeys =  new TreeSet<GregorianCalendar>(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().keySet());
                        for(GregorianCalendar remove: toRemove){
                                    copyKeys.removeAll(Collections.singleton(remove));

                        }
```

And I am trying to remove every occurrence of the key "remove" in my TreeSet copyKeys. But it only seems to remove one of them. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Please let me know if you need more information.

EDIT:
For the sake of it, here is my entire mess of a method (I know it has a few more issues that just the question that I am asking), but here is goes:

```
    public void eventList(){

        int year = -1;
        GregorianCalendar tempKey = null;
        ArrayList<Event> tempArr = new ArrayList<Event>();
        ArrayList<GregorianCalendar> toRemove = new ArrayList<GregorianCalendar>();
        int countEnd = 0;

        if(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().equals(null)){
            System.out.println("Your calendar is empty!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Here are your events: ");
            SortedSet<GregorianCalendar> keys = new TreeSet<GregorianCalendar>(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().keySet());
            SortedSet<GregorianCalendar> copyKeys =  new TreeSet<GregorianCalendar>(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().keySet());
            tempKey = keys.first();
            int countTotal = keys.size();
            for(GregorianCalendar key : copyKeys){
                GregorianCalendar copyKey = key;
                Event value = MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(key);
//              System.out.println(" key.get(Calendar.MONTH) = " + key.get(Calendar.MONTH));
//              System.out.println("(tempKey.get(Calendar.MONTH)) = " + (tempKey.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
//              System.out.println(" key.get(Calendar.DATE) = " + key.get(Calendar.DATE));
//              System.out.println(" tempKey.get(Calendar.DATE) = " + (tempKey.get(Calendar.DATE)));
                tempArr.add(value);
                countEnd++;
                if(key.get(Calendar.MONTH) == (tempKey.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                        && key.get(Calendar.DATE) == (tempKey.get(Calendar.DATE))
                        && key.get(Calendar.YEAR) == tempKey.get(Calendar.YEAR)){

                        //  tempArr.add(value);
                            if(key.get(Calendar.YEAR) != year){
                                System.out.println(key.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                                year = key.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                                    System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                                            + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");

                            }

                            toRemove.add(copyKey);
//                          toRemove.add(copyKey);
                            //keys.remove(copyKey);

                }else{
                    //if(count <= 1){
                        //if(tempArr.size() == 1){
                    if(countEnd == countTotal){
                        tempArr.remove(tempArr.size() - 1); 
                    }else{
                        if(tempArr.size() > 1){
                            tempArr.remove(tempArr.size() - 2); 
                        }else{
                            tempArr.remove(tempArr.size() - 1); 
                        }

                        if(toRemove.size() > 0){
                            toRemove.remove(toRemove.size() - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    //  }
//                      else{
//                          tempArr.remove(tempArr.size() - 2); 
//                          toRemove.remove(toRemove.size() - 1);
//                      }
//                      
                    //  count = 0; //reset matches
                    //}

                }
                tempKey = key;


            }
                Collections.sort(tempArr);
                for(Event e: tempArr){

                            if(e.endTime != null){

                                System.out.println("    " + e.eventName + " " + e.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
                                e.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + e.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
                                + ":" + e.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                                //tempKey = key;
                            //  year = key.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
                                //keys.remove(key);
                            }
                            else{
                                System.out.println("    " + e.eventName + " " + e.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
                                        e.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                            //  tempKey = key;
                            //  year = key.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
                                //keys.remove(key);
                            }
                }
                        tempArr.clear();
                        //break;


                        for(GregorianCalendar remove: toRemove){
                                    copyKeys.removeAll(Collections.singleton(remove));

                        }


                for(GregorianCalendar key : copyKeys){
                        Event value = MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(key);

                    if(tempArr.size() == 0){
                    if(value.endTime != null){
                        if(key.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year){

                            System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                                    + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " - " + value.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
                                    + ":" + value.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.eventName);
                        //  tempKey = key;

                        }else{
                            System.out.println(key.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                            System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                                    + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " - " + value.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
                                    + ":" + value.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.eventName );
                            year = key.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            tempKey = key;
                        }

                    }else{
                        if(key.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year){
                            System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                                    + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.eventName);
                            tempKey = key;

                        }else{
                            System.out.println(key.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                            System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                                    + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)  + " " + value.eventName);
                            System.out.println();
                            year = key.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            tempKey = key;
                        }
                    }
                    }


                }

        }

    }
```

I originally have it sorted by the keys (dates) in ascending order. From there, I am looking for any identical dates and sorting them by the time (values). Then, since I've already sorted and printed those days by the time, I don't want to reprint them later. I've been tweaking this for hours to try to get it to cooperate, so perhaps I'm over thinking it at this point. Anyway, if anyone is nice enough to look at this and make a few suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it. Otherwise, just skip over because this is a long and convoluted one.

Comment: By definition a `Set` only contains one of a given key.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But if I print that set after removal, it still prints that key and it's value. Is it not deleting at all then?

Comment: A `Set` isn't a `Map`.... there's only the value (or key if your prefer) in a `Set`.

Comment: I've edited my original post with the rest of the method to clarify how it works. It's a bit hard to explain. But it's messy, so please don't feel like you have to go through it all. I am using a key set, but I'm able to extract the values from it as well. I have it sorted by the key, and now I want to sort it by the value as well.

Answer (score 0):

There will only be one occurrence of any given object in a Set and that is why only one is being removed.

Sets do not allow duplicates. If you want to allow duplicates, use another data structure such as an ArrayList.

Comment: But regardless, shouldn't that occurrence still get removed? I have that same key but with multiple values (to in my test case), but after the removal, I am still printing one of the values of that key.

Comment: The removal of an object from a Set will only occur once until you add the object to the Set again. Even if you attempt to add an object to a Set multiple times, it does not allows duplicates so the Set will only contain one instance of that object. If you want to map keys to objects, you can use a Map.

Comment: However a Map does not allow duplicates either. If you want to map a key to multiple objects, you can do something like this: `Map<String, List<GregorianCalendar>> multimap=new Map<String, List<GregorianCalendar>>();` where your key is a String which maps to multiple GregorianCalendar objects.

Comment: I've edited in my entire method. Perhaps it will clarify my problem. Then again, it's kind of a mess, so it might just make it more confusing. Please view at your own discretion if you'd like. I'm just out of ideas about how to get it to work properly.

Comment: But removing the object from the set does remove all occurrences of it as there is only ever one occurrence of a given object in a set. I looked through your code but I don't understand the problem as you are guaranteed that once you remove it, there will not be any occurrences of this object left in the set.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. Originally, I wasn't event trying to remove all occurrences, I was just removing the one key. But it somehow manages to print it again one more time in the last loop for(GregorianCalendar key : copyKeys){

Comment: You could iterate through the set and print out its values to see what it contains. If your set contains objects that appear to be duplicates, the objects which appear to be duplicates may have very slight differences. For example, in your example above, the GregorianCalender objects may have the same dates and times but their milliseconds might be different and therefore they would be considered unique objects.

Comment: If you think two GregorianCalender objects are the same (e.g. object1 and object2), check if `object1.equals(object2)` returns true or false. If it returns false, they may have very slight differences as mentioned in my previous comment and therefore these two objects would be allowed to be contained in the same Set simultaneously as the Set would use GregorianCalender's `equals` method to check for duplicates.

Comment: They must be equal because when I put a testing print statement in my deletion loop, it passes the check and says that it's deleting.

Comment: Yes but as you said _Originally, I wasn't event trying to remove all occurrences, I was just removing the one key. But it somehow manages to print it again one more time in the last loop for(GregorianCalendar key : copyKeys){ –_ Therefore if objects which you think are equal are being successfully added to the same Set, they are not entirely equal as a Set does not allow duplicates.

Comment: I was using the same print statement then, it was always going in to the deletion block successfully.